# Instagram api not-working

Tags: instagram

I trying to use instagtram api. But endpoints: comments and likes not working.

```
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/
```

[image]

But if I try to get comments - Data is empty.

What`s wrong?

[image]

Comment: Anyone help, please!

Answer (score 1):

Instagram API after Jun'16 is so unusable.

Try fetch this `https://www.instagram.com/query/?q=ig_shortcode(BK07W-Xhq6S){comments.last(20){count,nodes{id,created_at,text,user{id,username,full_name}},page_info}}` and you receive JSON with comments data.

Comment: where i can read official documentation? I read is there https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/

Comment: @КамаловРадик this is unofficial solution.

Comment: Maybe since Nov '16 or so this is giving 405 http status. Did instagram just pull a twitter move and kill off some 3rd party apps?